# Ignore SSL cert for private PyPi

Tags: python, ssl, pypi

I have a a private PyPi repository, however the test server does not have a valid ssl certificate for its domain. When uploading the test package, i.e.,

`python setup.py sdist upload -r privatepypi`

I get this error:

`ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'pypi.xxx.com' doesn't match either of 'www.yyy.com', 'api.yyy.com', 'pypi.yyy.com'`

is it possible to tell it to ignore the server ssl certificate?